# Command pattern which folder

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I want to use the command pattern to create a `Request` class with the children `LoginRequest` and `RegisterRequest`. But in which folder should I put these classes? Or should I create a new folder and how should I call this new folder?

This is how my folder structure looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JmrO.png

Comment: Coudl you add some more informations about these classes? What they would have?

Comment: The `LoginRequest ` class would have this implementation link: http://pastebin.com/XxHXFq4p  And the `RegisterRequest` would have this implementation link: http://pastebin.com/ArwJnXiE  The `Request` class would have an abstract method. Where the children put their implementation.

Comment: Ok, so as I've already expected. I edited my post. If you have any question, please free to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to GitHub projects, which have these or similar namesd of methods there are more than three possible ways

1. Create a `registration` folder like [here](https://github.com/szymie/MotionRecorder/blob/95e452e84606cf8c2eabdb664a5b2e4bf4fd50c0/app/src/main/java/put/iwm/android/motionrecorder/registration/RegisterRequestBuilder.java)
2. Create `aidl` folder
3. Create `api/request` package like [here](https://github.com/gaoge/duoduo/blob/effdc10caa4e6e0ffaa2c69917e24b6fe658ec2d/duoduoAPI/src/com/duoduo/api/request/RegisterRequest.java)

But the best is the third one, I'm already using this pattern.

Creating `api` folder and than subfolders into it like `model` and `request` would keep your project structure really clean and readable for other developers